# I am having trouble finding specific links from one site

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So yes, I would like to pull all the links that lead me to raffles

[image: raffle link location]

I know what the command is for finding the links I need.

```
elems = chrome.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
for elem in elems:
    print(elem.get_attribute("href"))
```

The problem is that it also finds things I don't need.

[image: poop]

Is there a command to search for these links only in elements with the class name "raffle-name"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
elems = chrome.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='raffle-name']/a[@href]")
for elem in elems:
    print(elem.get_attribute("href"))
```

use the above xpath

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expresions, like:

```
Xpath=//a[starts-with(@href,'raffles')]
```

or contains. Learn more on https://www.guru99.com/using-contains-sbiling-ancestor-to-find-element-in-selenium.html